# How to get the return value of a php function when calling from jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a php function return a string value which will put into html file.

```
function getDirectionInfo($routeNumber) {
    //some code here
    $dirinfo = "<p> some text </p>";
    return $dirinfo;
}

if (isset($_POST['getDirectionInfo'])) {
    getDirectionInfo($_POST['getDirectionInfo']);
}
```

So in jQuery, I have a following function

```
$(".onebtn").click(function(){
    $("#directioninfo").empty();
    var routeNumber = $(this).text();
    $.ajax({
        url: "./systemView_Function.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {"getDirectionInfo": routeNumber},
        success: function(data) {   
            console.log("HIHIHIHI");
            $("#directioninfo").append(data);
        }
    });
})
```

Now console.log prints the "HIHIHIHIHI", but jQuery does not append the data to html. Anyone know how to get the return value of php function when calling from jQuery?

Comment: Your php code does not return anything. You call the function from within your conditional, but do nothing with the returned value.

Comment: You need to print something rather than return it

Comment: @Clive Actually that is not true.

Comment: If you don't print it how does it get back to the client @arkascha?

Comment: @Clive You might want to read a bit more about php. If you "return" something from the top layer it get's send to the output. Which basically comes out the same than "printing" ("output" would be better here). But "returning" actually makes more sense from a logical point of view.

Comment: I've read plenty, thanks. What you're describing may well be a feature, but it's not a commonly used one. Explicitly writing to the output buffer is standard fare in my experience

Comment: I don't see why returning something would output it. I've never experienced this behavior or seen anything written on it. @arkascha, Could you provide a link to some documentation on this behavior? In my experience echoing or printing is required.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of return use:

```
echo json_encode($dirinfo);
die;
```

It's also good idea to add `dataType` field to your `$.ajax()` function params set to `json`, to make sure, that data in your success function will be properly parsed.

Comment: so how can I retrieve the data from the json format?

Comment: Change `console.log("HIHIHIHI");` to `console.log(data);` and check what you get.

Comment: Well, could you try to put e.g. `echo json_encode(array('test')); die;` at the beginning of your php script and check if ajax call could retrieve any data?

Comment: So probably you should change your output . You can put `$dirinfo` into array as follows: `echo json_encode(array('content' => $dirinfo));`. The you can append it just using `data.content`.

Comment: i tried `data.content` and `data["content"]`, it is not working.

Comment: I have tried `echo json_encode(array("content"⇒"test"));` and it works. However, when I changed back to `echo json_encode(array("content"=>$dirinfo));`, it does not work. I have a feeling that the ajax did not go through the whole php function.

Comment: Make sure that your php function is executed corectly and there is no errors before you get to the end.

Comment: I have found out there was an error in jQuery. I should use `var routeNumber = parseInt($(this).text());` instead of `var routeNumber = $(this).text();`. I have also learn something from your answer. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

1. You just need to send the response back using `echo`
2. Use  `var routeNumber = $(this).val();` to get the button value

**PHP:**

```
<?php
function getDirectionInfo($routeNumber) {
    //some code here
    $dirinfo = "<p> routeNumber". $routeNumber." </p>";
    return $dirinfo;
}

if (isset($_POST['getDirectionInfo'])) {
    echo getDirectionInfo($_POST['getDirectionInfo']);
}else{
    echo "not set";
}
```

**AJAX & HTML**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".onebtn").click(function(){
  $("#directioninfo").empty();
  var routeNumber = $(this).val();
  console.log("routeNumber = " + routeNumber);
  $.ajax({
   url: "systemView_Function.php",
   type: "POST",
   data: {"getDirectionInfo": routeNumber},
   success: function(data) {   
    console.log("data = " + data);
    $("#directioninfo").append(data);
   }
  });
 })
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="directioninfo"></div>
 <input type="button" value="12346" class="onebtn" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you, actually i found out `var routeNumber = parseInt($(this).text());` should be instead of `var routeNumber = $(this).text();` so that the rest works.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for everyone. I have just found that I made a very stupid mistake in jQuery. I should use `var routeNumber = parseInt($(this).text());` instead of `var routeNumber = $(this).text();` So the following code work to get the return value of php function when calling from jQuery.

in php

```
function getDirectionInfo($routeNumber) {
    //some code here
    $dirinfo = "<p> some text </p>";
    echo json_encode($dirinfo);
}

if (isset($_POST['getDirectionInfo'])) {
    getDirectionInfo($_POST['getDirectionInfo']);
}
```

in jQuery

```
$(".onebtn").click(function(){
    $("#directioninfo").empty();
    var routeNumber = parseInt($(this).text());
    $.ajax({
        url: "./systemView_Function.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {"getDirectionInfo": routeNumber},
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data) {   
            $("#directioninfo").append(data);
        }
    });
})
```